# c# how to trigger a method in code based on a dynamic table value

Tags: c#

I have a code that controls a kind of questionnaire flow.

All questions are in the database and a question could have multiple answers. Some answers are just plain text that triggers a second question but some are boolean replies such I could wait for a Yes or a No.

Right now I literally have a logic that has a switch based on an enumerator that corresponds to the question and then I manually check if the response was "Yes" or "No". For example:

```
  case Question.CancelAppointment:

                                    // match text sent with question possible keywords
                                    templateKeyword = _messageRepo.GetMessageTemplateKeyword(conversation.CurrentTemplateId.Value, messageReceived);
                                    if (templateKeyword != null && templateKeyword.ReplyTemplateId > 0)
                                    {
                                        if(templateKeyword.Keyword == "yes")
                                        {
                                            // Do something here
                                        }else {
                                           // Do something here
                                        }
                                       

                                    }
```

This is the table where I link a question to multiple keyword options:

[image]

I don't like this method because will be a lot of hardcoded logic for checking each replied keyword, so I would like to have something more elegant.

Maybe in the database, I could have another column where I could have a method name or a class and then in code get that value and by some mechanism trigger that instead of doing this kind of if statements for checking the keyword and matches a value.

Let's say if the user responds to "Yes" I want to perform a database check and some inserts in the same database plus other things. Instead of having the IF statement hardcoded YES, maybe this new column linked for the YES keyword will have a "QuestionTwoSuccessMethod" string that is the name of the method that I want to execute in code.

Any clue?

Comment: Hard to know what you really want here. You haven't actually asked a proper question, and it's also unclear exactly what logic you are trying to represent, so we can't even begin to guess.

Comment: you could have a dictionary of delegates, action, func.... with a string key. but then again i dont see anything wrong with checking the string and firing some logic.